# Adding a column with a static value in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

It's a very basic question but I'm still confused.

I need to add a column(**country_code**) to store the country's ISO code ('**CYP**') as a static value in a Table (**TableA**)

What would be the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a check constraint on it that checks if it's `'CYP'`.

```
ALTER TABLE tablea
            ADD country_code varchar(3)
                             NOT NULL
                             DEFAULT 'CYP';
ALTER TABLE tablea
            ADD CHECK (country_code = 'CYP');
```

Though you might reconsider that. If it's `'CYP'`  either way, there not much point in storing that value. You can always add `'CYP'` as a literal in your queries when you need it. For convenience you can also create a view that contains it, so that you don't have to write it in every query again and again.

Comment: How about a view?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: Right, I missed that one... Included it in an edit. Thanks!

Comment: You could also add a generated column, that would also throw an error if you tried to modify it.